# Creating a hierarchy of methods in a class?

Tags: python

I have class with hundreds of methods
I want create a hierarchy of them that will let easy find method.

For example

```
class MyClass:
    def SpectrumFrequencyStart()...
    def SpectrumFrequencyStop()...
    def SpectrumFrequencyCenter()...
    def SignalAmplitudedBm()...
```

That I want to call using:

```
MyClassObject.Spectrum.Frequency.Start()
MyClassObject.Spectrum.Frequency.Stop()
MyClassObject.Signal.Amplitude.dBm()
```

Comment: No. You can't do that. `.` means an access to an object's attribute. Since you don't have objects called `Spectrum` and `Signal` in `MyClass` this can not be done.

Comment: What precisely do you mean by *"I want create hierarchy of them that will let easy find method [sic]"*? Why don't you just split it down into more, smaller objects along the lines you describe?

Comment: Seems like you want encapsulate the related chunks of method in an object and put that object in`MyClass.Spectrum` etc.

Comment: "I have class with hundreds of methods" - this is very bad already.

Comment: @Elmo: Indeed...and that's what the OP wants to fix.

Comment: @martineau And therefore my answer to the question is just dozens of pixels below ;)

Comment: Hi, i want to explain where i need this approach. For example i have DLL with many functions and i want to wrap this DLL in Python, but i don't want just class with flat hierarchy of functions, but to do some hierarchy

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a dictionary to map your methods to keys (either hierarchical dictionaries, or simply '.' separated keys).

Another option which may be more elegant is [namedtuples](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple). Something like:

```
from collections import namedtuple
MyClassObject = namedtuple('MyClassObject', ['Spectrum', 'Signal'])
MyClassObject.Spectrum = namedtuple('Spectrum', ['Frequency'])
MyClassObject.Spectrum.Frequency = namedtuple('Frequency', ['Start', 'Stop'])
MyClassObject.Spectrum.Frequency.Start = MyClass.SpectrumFrequencyStart
```

- You can automate this by using [inspection](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html) and parse the method names by, say camel case, to build the namedtuples automatically.
- Pay attention to binding of the methods

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo The questions starts from an Antipattern to begin with. I assume he did not look for someone to tell him to rewrite his code, right? He asked for programatic solution.
I did not answer a question about proper software engineering.
You are welcome to comment, but downvoting is excessive. Solution is useful, even if just give an idea or direction to the reader.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem Indeed the question starts from an antipattern. The problem X is a very poor class design. Solution Y which OP is asking for is to hack the language to ease access to hundreds of methods. It has to be clearly stated that it's not the way to go. While I appreciate your knowledge about collections module and method bindings, I don't see how it helps OP to use object oriented programming paradigm correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a very bad design.
It's clear that `Spectrum`, `Signal`, `Frequency` (and so on) should be all separate classes with much less than "hundreds of methods".
I'm not sure if MyClassObject actually represents something or is effectively just a namespace.
Objects can encapsulate objects of other classes. For example:

```
class Frequency(object):

    def start(self):
        pass

    def stop(self):
        pass


class Spectrum(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.frequency = Frequency()


class Amplitude(object):

    def dbm(self):
        pass


class Signal(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.amplitude = Amplitude()


class MyClass(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.spectrum = Spectrum()
        self.signal = Signal()


my_class_instance = MyClass()
my_class_instance.spectrum.frequency.start()
my_class_instance.spectrum.frequency.stop()
my_class_instance.spectrum.signal.amplitude.dbm()
```

There's a convention of code formatting in Python [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) therefore I applied it in my example.